# Firebase Emulator - upload suddenly stopped working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, cloud, storage, emulation

Currently building a spa using firebase emulator and Vue.  All of a sudden its stopped being able to write to storage and firestore.
After drilling down into the debug.log I've found what I think could be the issue
command requires scopes
Https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud platform projects.readonly

Really not sure where to start resolving this so any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: What's your device android version?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've resolved the issue. Seems that my Google cloud trial ended and as such the api and cloud link to the firebase project stopped working. By sorting out the cloud trial then creating a new firebase project, resetting my fb config to the new project the issue has resolved.